# Breeze: addEntityType with complexType (entityTypes aggregation)

Tags: javascript, .net, breeze

I have .NET entity:

```
public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BornOn { get; set; }        
    public string RegisteredAddress { get; set; }
    public string ResidentalAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I use this code to create client-side analogue in Breeze:

```
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'Customer',
            namespace: 'ClientSide.App',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: types.long, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                firstName: { dataType: types.string },
                middleName: { dataType: types.string },
                lastName: { dataType: types.string },
                bornOn: { dataType: types.datetime },
                registeredAddress: { dataType: types.string },
                residentalAddress: { dataType: types.string },
                lastNameWithInitials: { dataType: types.string },
                phone: { dataType: types.string },
                mobilePhone: { dataType: types.string },
                email: { dataType: types.string }
            }
        });
```

Right now, i have new server side property:

```
public Passport Passport { get; set; }
```

as

```
public class Passport
{
    public string Series { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssuedOn { get; set; }
    public string IssueAuthority { get; set; }
}
```

And i can't figure out how could i add it in Breeze?

**Update:**

Could it be done without `getter` property like this:

```
public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            var contact = Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ContactType.Phone);
            return contact != null ? contact.Value : "";
        }
    }
```

Is there other way?

Comment: How does the Phone relate to your Passport question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Passport` is what Breeze would call a [ComplexType](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/complextype-properties).
You should add metadata describing the Passport type, then add it as a property of Customer:

```
    store.addEntityType({
        shortName: 'Passport',
        namespace: 'ClientSide.App',
        isComplexType: true,
        dataProperties: {
            series: { dataType: types.string },
            number: { dataType: types.string },
            issuedOn: { dataType: types.datetime },
            issueAuthority: { dataType: types.string }
        }
    });

    store.addEntityType({
        shortName: 'Customer',
        namespace: 'ClientSide.App',
        dataProperties: {
            id: { dataType: types.long, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
            firstName: { dataType: types.string },
            // ... other properties ...
            passport: { complexTypeName: "Passport", isNullable: false}
        }
    });
```

This is described in the [Metadata by Hand - In Depth](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-hand-depth) page of the documentation, 
about halfway down the page.